# Alfresco CMIS parents query returning unexpected empty result

Tags: alfresco, cmis

## Context

The CMIS `parent` operation allows one to get the full path(s) of an object from its id.
For instance, I give `/alfresco/service/cmis/s/versionStore:version2Store/i/2f4cbf7a-0f8e-4fa1-81e5-8be69eb0532e` and I get `/Sites/swsdp/documentLibrary/Presentations`.

I have an Alfresco Community 4.2.e server.
Not sure if relevant but it is purely out-of-the-box except I [enabled ChangeLog](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/CmisSync/wiki/How-to-enable-CMIS%27-ChangeLog-feature-on-Alfresco):

```
audit.enabled=true
audit.alfresco-access.enabled=true
audit.cmischangelog.enabled=true
```

## What occurs

When I run a ["parent" CMIS request](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/CMIS-v1.1-cs01.html#x1-4630001) below, I get the response below which contains zero Atom entries:

```
GET /alfresco/service/cmis/s/versionStore:version2Store/i/2f4cbf7a-0f8e-4fa1-81e5-8be69eb0532e/parents?includeAllowableActions=false&includeRelationships=none&includeRelativePathSegment=true HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Apache Chemistry DotCMIS
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Host: 192.168.0.66:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; type=feed;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 06 Mar 2014 06:57:46 GMT

477
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/" xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/" xmlns:alf="http://www.alfresco.org" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<author><name>admin</name></author>
<generator version="4.2.0 (r56674-b4848)">Alfresco (Community)</generator>
<icon>http://192.168.0.66:8080/alfresco/images/logo/AlfrescoLogo16.ico</icon>
<id>urn:uuid:2f4cbf7a-0f8e-4fa1-81e5-8be69eb0532e-parents</id>
<link rel="service" href="http://192.168.0.66:8080/alfresco/service/cmis"/>
<link rel="self" href="http://192.168.0.66:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/versionStore:version2Store/i/2f4cbf7a-0f8e-4fa1-81e5-8be69eb0532e/parents?includeAllowableActions=false&amp;includeRelationships=none&amp;includeRelativePathSegment=true"/>
<link rel="via" href="http://192.168.0.66:8080/alfresco/service/cmis/s/versionStore:version2Store/i/2f4cbf7a-0f8e-4fa1-81e5-8be69eb0532e"/>
<title>text1.txt Parents</title>
<updated>2014-03-05T16:32:44.359+09:00</updated>
</feed>
0
```

## What I think should occur

For reference, the CMIS standard has an example [request](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/examples/atompub/getObjectParents-request.log)/[response](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/cs01/examples/atompub/getObjectParents-response.log) for `parents`.
The example response contains an Atom entry which has the path I am looking for:

```
<atom:entry>
    [...]
    <cmisra:object xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/">
        <cmis:properties>
            [...]
            <cmis:propertyString queryName="cmis:path" displayName="Path" localName="cmis:path" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:path">
                <cmis:value>/My_Folder-0-0/MultifiledFolder1</cmis:value>
```

## Question

Why is Alfresco not giving me any Atom entry?

What is wrong with my request? I am pretty sure the id refers correctly to the existing file `/Sites/swsdp/documentLibrary/Presentations/test1.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a deprecated CMIS endpoint with an outdated CMIS implementation.

Try:

```
http://<host>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.0/atom
```